# Test for function's existence that can work on both bash and zsh?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, function

Is there a way to test whether a shell function exists that will work both for `bash` and `zsh`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to check that there's a currently defined (or at least potentially marked for autoloading) function by the name `foo` regardless of whether a builtin/executable/keyword/alias may also be available by that name, you could do:

```
if typeset -f foo > /dev/null; then
  echo there is a foo function
fi
```

Though note that if there's a keyword or alias called `foo` as well, it would take precedence over the function (when not quoted).

The above should work in `ksh` (where it comes from), `zsh` and `bash`.

Answer (score 4):

This is pure POSIX, so it should work on all POSIX shells.

```
foo()
{
    echo "bar"
}

if type 'foo' 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'function'
then
   echo 'function exists'
fi
```

Comment: This would also succeed if `foo` was an alias or an existing command instead of a function ... which may or may not matter depending on what OP intends to do with the function.

Comment: well of course you can add type foo | grep "foo.*function". The bash shell will print the function definition as well. zsh shell will simply inform type is function.